Combining broken rational invariants
(Came up with the Euler brick. $U,V,W,X,Y,Z$ are some combinations of lengths.)
One transformation keeps the values of $U,V$ invariant. Another the values of $W,Z$. A third $X,Y$. There are polynomial equations between the six variables, of which only two are independent:
$X-U-Z=0,UW+V(X^2+UX+1)=0,UY-(X^2-UX+1)=0,X^2(U^2-V^2-1)+2XU(4-3U^2)+U^4-11U^2-V^2-1=0$
(The exact form isn't relevant, just that I can't get the square roots and potential denominators away.) Is there a technique that allows to construct a new polynomial invariant (say) $P=f(U,Z),Q=g(U,Z)$ which is invariant under all transformations?
